# pwrss::power.t.test warning - "alternative = 'less' but non-centrality parameter is positive"

Tags: r

I am attempting to calculate the power required to detect a hypothetical change (30% increase and then also a 30% decrease) in mean density (log(x+1) transformed). Using the formula from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92993/noncentrality-parameter-what-is-it-what-does-it-do-what-would-be-a-suggested), my non-centrality parameter (ncp) value is positive (in both situations). When alternative="less", it produces the following warning.

```
# 30% hypothetical increase
power.t.test(ncp = (0.4940*sqrt(47)), # ncp = ((ln_up = 0.4940)*sqrt(n=47)) = 3.386693
             df = 46,                 # df = n-1 = 46
             alpha = 0.05,
             alternative = "less",
             plot = TRUE)

     power ncp.alt ncp.null alpha df  t.crit
 0.9546192   3.387        0  0.05 46 1.67866

Warning message:
alternative = 'less' but non-centrality parameter is positive
```

My main question is how do I solve the issue of the warning (I assume these power calculations are wrong)? What is the correct ncp formula that calculates both negative and positive values, given my data?

Data:

```
structure(list(Season = "DRY", assem = "Far", n = 47L, mean_log_den = 0.38, 
    ln_up = 0.494, ln_down = 0.266), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
    Season = "DRY", .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

- mean_log_den = mean log(x+1) transformation of density (data is right-skewed with many zeros)
- ln_up = 0.4940 = hypothetical 30% increase of mean_log_den
- ln_down = hypothetical 30% decrease of mean_log_den

Comment: I'm confused about where your confusion lies. If the alternative is "less" then shouldn't the ncp be negative (Or at a minimum less than the NULL under the H_0)? Your value (0.4940*sqrt(47)) appears to be neither.

Comment: BTW 3.386693 is the result I get at my R console for `0.38*sqrt(47))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mu_0 = 0.3799 # Null hypothesis (no change in mean)
mu = 0.2659   # Alternative (30% decline in mean)
n = 47        # Sample size per group
d = -0.114    # Direction of change
sd = 0.4352   # Sample sd
cor = 0.5     # R assumed correlation between repeated measures

# 3 options...
ncp_1 = (mu - mu_0) * sqrt(n)/sd

ncp_2 = d / (sd / sqrt(n))

ncp_3 = d * sqrt(n) / sqrt(2*sd^2 * (1 - cor))

pwrss::power.t.test(ncp = c(ncp_1, ncp_2, ncp_3), 
                    df = n-1,
                    alpha = 0.05,
                    alternative = "less",
                    plot = FALSE)

     power ncp.alt ncp.null alpha df  t.crit
 0.5495299  -1.796        0  0.05 46 1.67866
 0.5495299  -1.796        0  0.05 46 1.67866
 0.5495299  -1.796        0  0.05 46 1.67866
```